# Writing extra lines to comma deliminated text files in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, text-files

I am trying to create a mini accounts application that captures and stores the first name, last name, student number and grade of students through textboxes and then stores it to a comma delimited text file.  The problem is that it re-writes the input every time I hit the save file.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is the code I am using:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim fName, lName, sNum As String
    Dim grade As Decimal

    fName = txtFName.Text
    lName = txtLName.Text
    sNum = txtSNum.Text
    grade = txtGrade.Text

    Try

        Dim write As StreamWriter
        write = New StreamWriter("hello.txt")
        write.WriteLine(String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", fName, lName, sNum, grade))
        write.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try



End Sub
```

Comment: What do you want the code to do?

Comment: `write = New StreamWriter("hello.txt", True)`.  your writer is leaking though

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim fName, lName, sNum As String
    Dim grade As Decimal

    fName = txtFName.Text
    lName = txtLName.Text
    sNum = txtSNum.Text
    grade = txtGrade.Text

    Try
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("hello.txt", String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", fName, lName, sNum, grade))
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also: it reads the content first and append this while writing

```
    Try
        Dim objReader = New StreamReader(FullPath)
        Dim str As String = objReader.ReadToEnd()
        objReader.Close()
        Dim write As StreamWriter
        write = New StreamWriter(FullPath)
        write.Write(str & vbNewLine & String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", fName, lName, sNum, grade))
        write.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```